# NativeScript cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, routes, nativescript

I'm super new at Angular and NativeScript and can't really figure out how to do the whole routing thing. Currently, I'm getting an error where it's saying

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'signIn'

Here's the .html, `home.component.html`, where my button is:

```html
   <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-sm" style="width: 90%; height: 7%; padding: 0px; margin: 5px; background-color: black; color: white; vertical-align: bottom;" text="Sign pIn" (tap)=onSignIn()></Button>
```

Here's the component, `home.component.ts`, where the function is:

```
onSignIn(): void { 
    this.router.navigate(['signIn']);
}
```

and then, here's my `signIn.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "SignIn",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./signIn.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./signIn.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit { }
```

Also, here's where my route is configured in my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
{ path: "signIn", redirectTo: "/signIn", pathMatch: "full" }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where have youu configured your route?

Comment: @Sajeetharan updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `redirect`, load the `component` over there. So you have to replace `redirectTo: "/signIn"` with `component: SignInComponent`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "signIn", component: SignInComponent, pathMatch: "full" }
];
```

See this small [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfj65i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

Note : And also you should not be redirecting to the same route, it would become recursive. At the end, angular will not find any component to load which might lead to

> cannot-match-any-routes error

Comment: Can u help me on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262183/assertion-failure-and-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-nativescript

Comment: @McDonal_11 Sorry, I have no idea about it.

Comment: I am trying to run in my device.  I don't know y .

Comment: Xcode 9.2, in simulator also, its showing this same error.